# Using DISTINCT and RANDOM with two Tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, distinct

I have this problem. I need to query ticket number from tickettable and member name from memberstable, with random function and distinct keyword in postgres. The MemberName should be unique.

this code works in mySQL but doesn't work in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT a.ticketNum, b.memberName 
FROM tickettable a, memberstable b 
GROUP BY memberName 
ORDER BY by rand()  
LIMIT 2
```

What should I do?

Comment: What error or output you are getting? Is there any common column for given tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random number function in Postgres is `random()`.  Second, the `group by` is not going to work because `ticketNum` is not included.  You can do what you want in several ways.  Here is a correlated subquery way:

```
SELECT m.memberName,
       (select t.ticketNum
        from tickettable t
        order by random()
        limit 1
       ) as ticketNum
FROM memberstable m
LIMIT 2;
```

In addition, note the following:

- The `,` in the `from` clause is replaced with `cross join`.  Avoid commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.
- The table aliases are abbreviates for the tables names, making the query easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you Very much sir Gordon Linoff.! The Code works. However, my desired result, didn't come up. The results in the ticketNum isn't distinct. And If I put DISTINCT before t.ticketNum an error occurs --- "[Err] ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list" ... what should I do? 

thank you :)

Comment: @JedAchas . . . Ask another question.  This one does not specify that the ticket numbers should be unique, only that they should be random.  That is a major change to the approach to the solution.